# D3D11InfoQueue Isn't filtering out messages

Tags: directx11

I have followed the Coordinator's code advice from this page on [how to query and filter the messages in the debug layer](https://web.archive.org/web/20171227183729/https://directxtk.codeplex.com/discussions/405099) but it doesn't seem to be working. You can see from the following code that I try to filter out 2 messages but they still keep zinging by in debug output. Does anyone know how to do this correctly? Here is the code:

```
void CDebugLayer::CreateD3DDebugLayer(void)
{
    if(SUCCEEDED(s_pApplication->m_spEngine->GetD3DObj()->m_spD3DDevice.Get()->QueryInterface( __uuidof(ID3D11Debug), (void**)s_spD3DDebug.GetAddressOf())))
    {
      if(SUCCEEDED(s_spD3DDebug.Get()->QueryInterface( __uuidof(ID3D11InfoQueue), (void**)s_spD3DInfoQueue.GetAddressOf())))
      {
         #ifdef _DEBUG
             s_spD3DInfoQueue->SetBreakOnSeverity(D3D11_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_CORRUPTION, true);
             s_spD3DInfoQueue->SetBreakOnSeverity(D3D11_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_ERROR, true);
             //s_spD3DInfoQueue->SetBreakOnSeverity(D3D11_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_WARNING, true);
             //s_spD3DInfoQueue->SetBreakOnSeverity(D3D11_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_INFO, true);
             //s_spD3DInfoQueue->SetBreakOnSeverity(D3D11_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_MESSAGE, true);
         #endif

         D3D11_MESSAGE_ID stHide [] =
         {
             D3D11_MESSAGE_ID_SETPRIVATEDATA_CHANGINGPARAMS,
             D3D11_MESSAGE_ID_OFFERRELEASE_NOT_SUPPORTED
             // Add more message IDs here as needed
         };


         D3D11_INFO_QUEUE_FILTER stFilter;
         memset(&stFilter, 0, sizeof(stFilter));
         stFilter.DenyList.NumIDs  = _countof(stHide);
         stFilter.DenyList.pIDList = stHide;
         HRESULT hr = s_spD3DInfoQueue->AddStorageFilterEntries(&stFilter);
         assert(hr == S_OK);

         D3D11_INFO_QUEUE_FILTER stFilter2;
         memset(&stFilter2, 0, sizeof(stFilter2));
         SIZE_T ByteLength;

         // Perform debug tracking to confirm what is being stored
         uiNumMsgs = s_spD3DInfoQueue->GetNumMessagesAllowedByStorageFilter(); // = 7
         hr = s_spD3DInfoQueue->GetStorageFilter(&stFilter2, &ByteLength);
         assert(hr == S_OK);
         uiNumMsgs = s_spD3DInfoQueue->GetNumMessagesDeniedByStorageFilter();  // = 0

         //Pass copy to Application then store in CEngine for global engine access
         s_pApplication->m_spEngine->SetDebug(s_spD3DDebug.Get());
      }
    }
} // CreateD3DDebugLayer
```

**EDIT**
This is the error message I'm trying to filter out:
D3D11 INFO: ID3D11DeviceContext::OfferResources: OfferResources is not supported on operating systems older than Windows 8.  It is valid to call OfferResources, and an offerred resource must still be acquired with ReclaimResources before using it, however there is no benefit to calling OfferResources on this operating system besides testing the code path for Windows 8. [ EXECUTION INFO #3146071: OFFERRELEASE_NOT_SUPPORTED]

Caused by:

```
ID2D1DeviceContext->EndDraw()
```

on Windows 7 Sp1 x64. Using Windows SDK 8.1.

Comment: I don't want to have to use [ID3D11InfoQueue::SetMuteDebugOutput()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before and after the culprit code that causes the messages.

Comment: Can you post the example output you are getting (i.e. the exact message number)? Where is your ``d3d11sdklayers.h`` coming from (legacy DirectX SDK, Windows 8.0 SDK, Windows 8.1 SDK)? What version of the OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

DirectX Control Panel overrides filters set by application.

Run DirectX Control Panel, click Edit Lists, make sure your app is not there.

*I had exactly same problem as you and it turned out this helps.*